# How do I see that $1-(1-\frac 1 M)^Q \approx \frac Q M$ (provided that $Q$ is small compared to $M$), where both $Q$ and $M$ are integers?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

> How do I see that $$1-(1-\frac 1 M)^Q \approx \frac Q M$$ (provided that $Q$ is small compared to $M$), where both $Q$ and $M$ are integers ?

The approximation is stated in a book without proof.

I've tried looking into some analysis and using the binomial expansion theorem, but haven't come to a conclusion.

Also, how "small" should $Q$ be compared to $M$ before the approximation is good ?

Comment: Using the [Taylor expansions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $-\ln(1-x)$ and $e^x$ around $0$, you get $$\begin{align}
1-\left(1-\frac 1 M\right)^Q &= 1-e^{Q\ln (1-\frac 1 M)} = 1-e^{-\frac{Q}{M} + o\!\left(\frac{Q}{M}\right)} = 1-\left(1-\frac{Q}{M} + o\!\left(\frac{Q}{M}\right)\right) \\&= \frac{Q}{M} + o\!\left(\frac{Q}{M}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: You buy an item and you get 1% discount. And because you are the first customer of 2015, another 1% of the remaining amount. Then, because 1% is really tiny anyway, this is almost the same thing as getting 1% of the total amount instead. So $(1-\tfrac1{100})^2 \simeq 1 - \tfrac{2}{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it compared with clement nice comment/answer is
$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\matrix{n\\k}\right)x^{k}y^{n-k}
$$
Putting in $x= -1/M$ and $y=1$ for convience.
We find
$$
(-\frac{1}{M} +1)^Q= \sum_{k=0}^{Q}\left(\matrix{Q\\k}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{M}\right)^{k}
$$
The first few terms are
$$
\left(\matrix{Q\\0}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{M}\right)^{0} + \left(\matrix{Q\\1}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{M}\right)^{1} + ...
$$ 
Which yields your result. The size of $x$ in this case determines you can truncate the binomal expansion to first order terms.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the geometric progression:
$$
\overbrace{\left(1{}+{}\left(1-\frac{1}{M}\right){}+{}\ldots{}+{}\left(1{}-{}\frac{1}{M}\right)^{Q-1}\right)}^{Q\mbox{ terms}}{}={}\frac{\left(1{}-{}\left(1{}-{}\frac{1}{M}\right)^Q\right)}{\left(1{}-{}\left(1{}-{}\frac{1}{M}\right)\right)}{}={}M\left(1{}-{}\left(1{}-{}\frac{1}{M}\right)^Q\right)
$$

For $M$ sufficiently large, each of the $Q$ terms on the *l.h.s* is approximately $1$. Therefore, their sum in this case is approximately $Q$, giving 
$$
\frac{Q}{M}\approx\left(1{}-{}\left(1{}-{}\frac{1}{M}\right)^Q\right)\,.
$$
For $Q$ and $M$ not integers, the argument required is more sophisticated.